# access codecommit from us-east-1 to ap-south-1 using eb deploy in aws

Tags: aws-codecommit

I have php codecommit repository in region us-east-1 and  php ec2 instace in ap-south-1 region in which codecommit is not supported.how i have to access codecommit  repo from us-east-1 to ap-south-1 region using eb deploy?

Answer (score 0):

Since AWS CodeCommit is not yet available in that region, you should be able to use your repository in us-east-1 as if it were any other non-CodeCommit repository with the eb cli. When setting up, if the CLI asks:

`Do you wish to continue with CodeCommit? (y/N) (default is n):`

Reply with `n`.

This should treat it as any ordinary git repository source, which should unblock you for `eb deploy`, etc.